# Yii on adding new record error : 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, sql, yii

Adding new record it gives an error:

> 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'data' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Data', 'id'),
    );
}
```

Here is my code for adding a new record:

```
public function actionAdd_Record()
{
    $users = new Users();
    $data = new Data();


    if (isset($_POST['Users']) && isset($_POST['Data'])) {

        if(!empty($_POST['Users_password'])) $_POST['Users']['password']=md5($_POST['Users_password']);
         $users->created_date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


        CActiveForm::validate(array($users, $data));
        $users->attributes = $_POST['Users'];
        $data->attributes = $_POST['Data'];

        $valid=$users->validate();
        $valid=$data->validate() && $valid;


        if($valid){
            $users->save();
            $data->save();

            $this->redirect(
                array('view_record',
                    'id'=> $users->id)
            );
        }
    }

    $this->render(
        'add_record', array(
            'users'=> $users,
            'data'=>$data
        )
    );
}
```

Here is the first table:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `investment_amount` float DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '投資額',
  `withdrawals` float DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '引出額',
  `investment_yield` float DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '運用利回り',
  `account_balance` float DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '口座残高',
  `status_account` enum('open','closed') DEFAULT 'open',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

and the second table:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(300) NOT NULL COMMENT '氏名',
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `user_type` enum('normal','admin') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'normal',
  `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

and it gives this error:

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`money_investment`.`data`, CONSTRAINT `FK_data_users` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)). The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `data` (`investment_amount`, `withdrawals`, `investment_yield`, `account_balance`, `status_account`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for help, I fixed my problem.

I added `$data->id=$users->id;` because second table had no idea about the id. See [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/#c9743).

```
if($valid){
$users->save();
$data->id=$users->id;
$data->save();


$this->redirect(
    array('view_record',
        'id'=> $users->id)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a yii or PHP issue, but a database issue.

You're trying to insert a record that violates the relationships you've defined regarding primary keys.  Things to check would be the relationships, as well as the field lengths.

It looks like you may still have a relationship defined on a column that doesn't exist (money_investment?)

Answer (score 0):

foreign key constraints do not allow you to enter data in child before parents..
sometimes sql engines innoDb and MyIsam ..
read out its functionality u will come to know what sql engine would be preferred to use under foreign key constraint's coming issues....

Answer (score 0):

you surly update your tables. 
Best way is to See in Model

```
public function relations()
```

and compare these relations with your tables. 
Any additional or wrong relation might create such problem.